# How to reference empty class name in code?

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, assemblies

I'm trying to reference a function (named `.qs()` on screenshots) in a class which name is empty (probably obfuscated) - obviously without success.

.NET decompiler shows it as `<<EMPTY_NAME>>`.

Is there any way to do it without deobfuscation?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Cheers.

Comment: Only through reflection.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in comment above - I was able to execute it using reflection. Thanks for help. Sadly I can't accept comment as an answer.